How do I get a single command line result into a variable in windows batch (.bat)?
I know this question has been asked and some sort of answers given, but I don't get proper return for the accepted answer. specifically I'm trying to get a src folder for wherever a user has set their p4 root to be.
In a command line the following returns the proper folder:
p4 -F %clientRoot% -ztag info

However, trying to assign that return to a variable in a batch file has been hell.
From previous versions of this question the accepted answer is to use:
for /f %%i in (p4 -F %%clientRoot%% -ztag info) do set src=%%i

I get ECHO is off, when I try to echo %src%, (with @echo off in the first line of the batch file). Otherwise, I get some p4 error about not being able to get info on the given file.
I can set a string variable easy enough, even using other environmental variables
@echo off
cls

set dst=%USERPROFILE%\Documents\maya\2023\
echo %dst%

Gives the return
C:\Users\johnnyBgud\Documents\maya\2023\

but trying to set the return for the p4 command line won't echo properly nor can I use it in any intelligible way.
set p4root=p4 -F %%clientRoot%% -ztag info
%p4root%

gives me the directory I want when I execute the variable.. but I can't use it
set src=%p4root%\Development
echo %src%

pause

I get a return of:
p4 -F %clientRoot% -ztag info\Development\


Have you tried this: @Set "src=", then @For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ('p4 -F %%clientRoot^^^%% -ztag info') Do @Set "src=%%G", followed by @If Defined src (Echo %src%& Pause).

My hunch is that this is an XY problem where the ultimate thing you're trying to do doesn't require you to store the client root in a batch file to begin with -- if you're scripting something in p4 that you want to be able to run on different clients, you almost certainly want to be using depot paths rather than trying to construct local paths based on the root.

cancel that... answer found here...
How can I retrieve the P4 ROOT variable value in a Windows Batch file?
the problem was indeed, between my chair and my keyboard.

Please at least try the option I offered in my comment, which without the pipe to findstr.exe, should be more efficient. It also works only with your provided command, i.e. your question! If you feel that you cannot be bothered trying my suggestion, I could just simply close your question as a duplicate.
